# Exchange 2016 DNString length mismatch

Tags: exchange

Running Exchange 2016 Standard on Windows Server 2016. (When I try to open ECP I got an error site "DNString length mismatch". Then a stack trace is displayed:

```
[FormatException: DNString length mismatch]
   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.SystemConfiguration.ExchangeVirtualDirectory.RemoveDNStringSyntax(MultiValuedProperty`1 objectDNString, ProviderPropertyDefinition propertyDefinition) +952
   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.PropertyBag.GetMultiValuedPropertyValue(ProviderPropertyDefinition propertyDefinition, Boolean createDefaultValueEntry) +465
   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.PropertyBag.get_Item(PropertyDefinition key) +91
   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ConfigurableObject.ValidateCalculatedProperty(ProviderPropertyDefinition propertyDefinition, PropertyBag propertyBag, List`1 errors, Boolean useOnlyReadConstraints, Boolean onlyCacheValue) +47
   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ConfigurableObject.ValidateRead(List`1 errors, IEnumerable`1 propertiesToValidate) +283
   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObject.ValidateRead(List`1 errors) +2205
   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ConfigurableObject.ValidateRead() +65
   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADDataSession.ObjectsFromEntries(SearchResultEntryCollection entries, String originatingServerName, IEnumerable`1 properties, ADRawEntry dummyInstance) +5188
   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADDataSession.InternalFind(ADObjectId rootId, String optionalBaseDN, ADObjectId readId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, IEnumerable`1 properties, Boolean includeDeletedObjects) +4528
   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADDataSession.Find(ADObjectId rootId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, IEnumerable`1 properties, Boolean includeDeletedObjects) +132
   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADDataSession.Find(ADObjectId rootId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, String callerFilePath, Int32 callerFileLine, String memberName) +322
   Microsoft.Exchange.HttpProxy.HttpProxyGlobals.LoadVirtualDirectoryFromAD() +1738
   Microsoft.Exchange.ExchangeSystem.LazyMember`1.GetLazyMemberInternal() +110
   Microsoft.Exchange.Clients.Owa.Core.VdirConfiguration.BaseCreateInstance() +51
   Microsoft.Exchange.Clients.Owa.Core.VdirConfiguration.get_Instance() +129
   Microsoft.Exchange.HttpProxy.Logon.get_UserNamePlaceholder() +47
   ASP.auth_logon_aspx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) +1472
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +114
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +39
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +79
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +8817
```

Last thing I tried was to recreate virtual directories OWA and ECP according to http://theitbros.com/recreate-owa-ecp-virtual-directories-exchange-server-2016/

But the command "Get-OwaVirtualDirectory" as well yields the error "DNString length mismatch".

I didn't find anything in the web related to this error. Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Which exchange 2016 version are you using? Is that one up to date? Can you add that info please? Also which ECP site are you using, did you tried that directly on the Exchange host via localhost?

Comment: It is standard edition and it seems to be up to date. I am trying to access ECP from localhost. When I'm trying from a remote  machine I got only a nondescriptive "An error happens" page.

Comment: You can check that list [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh135098(v=exchg.150).aspx) to validate if the server is really up to date. In the past there where some ECP issue which where solved, so before we do a in deep troubleshooting it would be useful to know if the version you are using is up to date.

Comment: Thank, I tried to update Exchange but the update failed also with the error "DNString length mismatch", leaving me with an half installed Exchange on the server. I had to completely remove Exchange.

Comment: And an fully uninstall and reinstall solved the issue? If not check which .net framework you have installed. Only the latest exchange cu supports 4.6 but not 4.7 and both versions might come true windows update...

Comment: No, I completely dumped Exchange. The nomal uninstallation process didn't work too, so I had to remove Exchange the "hard way" with ADSI Edit. I took over the server from someone else 2 weeks ago and I have no idea what he did do. Thankfully this wasn't excactly a production server.